# Ansible cannot run global npm package

Tags: node.js, ansible

When executing the following scripts where 'bappo-migrate' is a global npm package:

```
- name: Install migration-cli globally
  npm:
    name: '@bappo/migration-cli'
    global: yes

- name: Run new migration scripts
  command: bappo-migrate upgrade chdir={{homeDir}}/bappo/bappo-api/mongo_migrations
  environment:
    PATH: '{{homeDir}}/.npm-global/bin:$PATH'
```

Ansible throws error:

```
{  
   "changed":false,
   "cmd":"bappo-migrate upgrade",
   "msg":"[Errno 2] No such file or directory",
   "rc":2
}
```

Cannot understand the error message - can confirm the directory exists and have tried manually executing the above commands, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment setting should be:

```
environment:
    PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:{{homeDir}}/.npm-global/bin"
```

As ansible can't deal with `$PATH` in `environment` correctly.

Here is [Source](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/faq.html).